# Telerik kendo grid and template for ForeignKey column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have this grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Worker>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    //columns.Bound(p => p.UserCard);
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.SecId, (List<UserCard>)ViewData["cards"], "Id", "Code").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey");
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.SecondName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Phone);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Email);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(220);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
    .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
    .Window(window=> window.Width(470))
    )
```

Grid show ForignColumn excelent
but when I try edit row in window my column SecId show like textblock not like combobox.
EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey")
this template placed in View/Shared/EditorTemplate/ and I didn't change it.
I just start create web apps and use telerik controls for asp.net so please help me understand what I do wrong.

Comment: did you try to describe your .Model, to set the id field? .Model(model => { model.Id(res => res.Id); }) How do you get/set the data for you dataSource?

Comment: I fix my problem, I use Window.TemplateName But I have another problem, I need use 2 different list for my SecId field, When I create item I must use one list and when edit I must use other list. And I didn't know how to do this `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SecId, new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["cards"],"Id","Code"))` Can I change ViewData["cards"] use JS?